# On page reload ionic 4 app doesn’t allow to key in any input

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-chrome, ionic4, angular7-router

We have ionic 4 web app, this application is deployed to AWS i.e. www folder. When I open the application it opens and I can perform required operations, but when I reload the application I can not key in any input and navigate from segments the app is totally blocked, not sure why is this happening only in my system. Is it an issue of lazy loading of components or issue with the browsers I am using?

When I right click and do inspect on chrome browser the block is released and I am able to key in input and navigate through out the app.

Please help me fix this issue. I mentioned my system config where I was testing this app. So far I have tried in chrome having 76.0 version and on microsoft edge having version 44.18362 browsers and my system config is OS: Windows 10, 64bit OS, Processor: i7, RAM: 8GB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution to fix this issue is to add the Cordova browser platform to your ionic app and do a prod build for browser.